# Can give me some advice about Web application architecture

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, web

In my opinion a common Web application architecture like this diagram(sorry as newer i can't update image~~~~)
Can someone give some advice about a common Web application architecture? thanks

**Application Server layer:**
 1. General execution environment that offers some type of
    middleware(ESB, ADF BCs, etc. ) tier support
 2. Exposes business logic to client applications through various
    protocols
 3. Provide an underlying infrastructure that includes automatic
    fault-tolerance, session mgmt, transaction mgmt, multi-threading -
    and everything else required to build scalable enterprise
    applications.

**Web Server layer**
 1. Handling HTTP requests
 2. Handling static files, index files
 3. Generate dynamic content(mvc framework)
 4. Accelerated reverse proxying
 5. Load balancing and fault tolerance
 6. Push data to a browser (realtime scenario)

**Browser Layer:**
 1. Javascript framework（UI component、event bus）
 2. Interaction Design
 3. Vision Design

Comment: how are you going to use that knowledge about "common" web application? Also, define what do you consider common.

Comment: Could you please ask a more specific question? On what topic do you want advice? What do you want to know?

Comment: "scalable enterprise applications" aren't a common web application.  Neither is Google or Facebook.   And web applications using Oracle's middle-tier architecture - ESB, ADF BC - are very rare.  So, as Sergio says, define *common*.  And define *web application* while you're at it.

Comment: Thought I'd see if there's anything quick and ready-made (surprisingly not a lot on Wikipedia). Found this nice piccie of [AppThenas architecture](http://www.appthena.com/developer/manual/architecture.html)  which looks "typical" if you like. Might be a good starting point before looking further into what lives in which layer (ESBs, web-app communication, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on what you've written:

- its pretty good
- I'd have taken line 3 out of web server layer and stuck in a hybrid
  class either with the app layer OR the browser layer, depending on
  how ajaxy / javascripty you plan on making the application (which is
  not to say I am saying you should combine views with application
  logic)

With that said, you actually end up with something like the following:

1. **Highest**: Web Server [load balancing, apache (etc), threading ...]
2. **High**: Application Server [Facebook would be using c++ here ...]
3. **In-Prep for High**: Server Side Client Dev [php / rails / django / asp here to consume the app server]
4. **End User**: Actual Client Dev [js to consume the server side client layer]

Also, new technologies like node are really starting to obscure the differences between those layers imho

Comment: APC is right,i want look a "scalable enterprise applications" ,so 'common" may not an appropriate  describe. thank everyone,I have learn more.

Answer (score 0):

One common architecture is a 3-tier architecture, where the layers are

```
Presentation layer
Responsible for rendering data
```

---

```
Business layer
Performing business logic.
Validating user data.
```

---

```
Data layer
Storing and retrieving business data
```

What you describe is a mix of infrastructure and software architecture. You really want to separate those two, and quite often the infrastructure part is already a given.